# Dynamic Navigation menu using php include

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, include

I am creating a website using HTML/bootstrap and to reduce the repetition of same code I tried using PHP include for footer and sidebar, like this:

```
 <html>
  <body>

    <?php include('navigation.php'); ?>

    Contents of this page here...

   <?php include('sidebar.php'); ?>
   <?php include('footer.php'); ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

I wanted to do the same thing for navigation menu also, But as the highlighted links changes with each page I am not sure how to change that dynamically.
Since I am using bootstrap just need some method by which I can manipulate the **class="active"** in the menu links.
(NB: new to php.)

Comment: In your php file, you can use conditionals (if/else/switch statements). Post some of your code for navigation.php?

Comment: `<li class="">
    <ul class="" >             
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>                            
       <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>                               
       <li class="active"><a href="#">privacy</a></li>                                
       <li><a href="#">about</a></li
   </ul>
 </li>`

Comment: I am looking for a method to move the class="active", to different links as the page changes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the structure of your site, but usually you would read the current url and set the active class according to that. So using, for example:

```
$current_page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

If you were at /index.php, then you would have

```
$current_page = '/index.php';
```

Then it is a simple matter of saying

```
<li<?php echo $current_page=='/index.php' ? ' class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li<?php echo $current_page=='/about.php' ? ' class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="">About</a></li>
```

This is just an example. Set the current page as above, see what the result is using echo, then set the link as below.

Answer (score 1):

There are tho easy ways to do that. The best way to me is to put the contents of your navigation.php file in a function which has an argument. Then you call the function after your include and you pass as argument a number or a string which represents the item you need to put as active.

Your function then would be something like this:

```
 <?php
 function displayNavBar($activeItem){ ?>
 <li class=""> 
      <ul class="" > <li <?php if($activeItem=="Home"){echo "class='active'";}?>>
         <a href="#">Home</a></li> <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>        <li class="active"><a href="#">privacy</a></li> <li><a href="#">about</a></li </ul> </li>

<?php } ?>
```

Obviously I have written the cose only for the first item, you need to do the same with the others. And then in your file you have to call the function created:

```
displayNavBar("Home"):
```